# Why is my flutter circular progress indicator keeps on loading?

Tags: flutter, dart

Can someone tell me why is my flutter circular progress indicator keeps rotating? I set isLoading to true in default and put it inside the builder container. Basically, it's an elevated button. When the button is pressed, a bottom sheet appears. Inside the bottom sheet, there is an image that takes time to load. I want the circular progress indicator to appear to show users' image is loading.

```
bool isLoading = true;


ElevatedButton(
            style:
                TextButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade200),
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: RichText(
                textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                text: TextSpan(
                  children: <TextSpan>[
                    TextSpan(
                      text: "Diploma in Business | ",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                    TextSpan(
                      text: "Taylor\u0027s",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              sendAnalyticsEvent(
                  eventName: "diplomainbusiness_taylors",
                  clickevent: "User clicked dipt");
              showModalBottomSheet(
                isScrollControlled: true,
                context: context,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                  top: Radius.circular(20),
                )),
                builder: (context) => Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      isLoading
                          ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                          : Image.network(
                              'https://i.imgur.com/bcAC3cA.jpg',
                            ),

                      ListTile(
                        title: Text(
                          'Test',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                        ),
                      ),
                      ListTile(
                        title: Text(
                          '• April and August Intake \n• 2 years programme\n• Scholarships available',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        child: Container(
                          width: double.infinity,
                          child: CupertinoButton.filled(
                            child: Text("Interested? Get more info!"),
                            onPressed: () => openBrowserTab(),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
```

Results:
[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think that I don't see any method that updates the state of the isLoading variable, when the image has loaded properly, you should change the value of the isLoading variable and then to change the state of the bottomModalSheet

Answer (score 1):

instead of using isLoading and need to change the state of the modalBottomSheet, you can use the loadingBuilder parameter of the Image.network like the  example below:

```html
Image.network(
      'https://i.imgur.com/bcAC3cA.jpg',
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
      loadingBuilder: (BuildContext context, Widget child,
          ImageChunkEvent loadingProgress) {
        if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
        return CircularProgressIndicator()
      },
    );
```

Hope it'll work

Comment: Thank you for your comment but I am getting this error "The argument type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, Widget, ImageChunkEvent)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, Widget, ImageChunkEvent?)?'.dartargument_type_not_assignable"

Comment: Oh nvm, I use this code instead

      Image.network(
                                  'https://i.imgur.com/bcAC3cA.jpg',
          loadingBuilder: (context, child, loadingProgress) {
            if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          },
),

and it works but, the circularprogressindiactor is slow to appear even bottom sheet is open.